# shouldn't this regex not match lines that have a preceding ';' in them?

Tags: regex

I have the following text sample:

```
    ; Obsidian__CTRL1_B(isHold, taps, state)
    Obsidian__CTRL1_N(isHold, taps, state)
  ; Opus__CTRL1_Z(isHold, taps, state)
  ; Opus__CTRL1_X(isHold, taps, state)
  ; Opus__CTRL1_C(isHold, taps, state)
```

I want to only match lines that do not have a preceding `;` in them, in other words only match line 2. I tried the regex, `[^;].*__ctrl1_.*\(`. As show on [RexEx101](https://regex101.com/r/cfNGNm/1), But this is matching all lines.

Isn't the first token`[^;]`, essentially saying don't match lines starting with ';'?

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: By default your regex engine probably has global match turned off. Try turning that on. The regex 101 example has global matching turned on in options.

Comment: Ah sorry misread, you have spaces at the start of your lines anyway, spaces match, you need to exclude whitespace characters such as tab/space etc in that negation `[^\s;]` should work (but that doesn't fix your issue, it just matches the extra characters), it sounds like you want to do a look ahead and NOT match?

Comment: All lines in your sample start with a space, so they all match. Please explain why all lines should not match your regex.

Comment: `(?m)^(?![ \t]*;).+` https://regex101.com/r/8rgpW8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to match lines whose first non-whitespace character is not a `;`.

Try this:

```
^\s*[^;\s].*__ctrl1_.*\(
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/6XrUZ2LV2K2xqW).

This matches start of line, any whitespace, then any character neither whitespace nor `;`, then the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Using `[^;]` by itself means a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and matches a single character other than `;` and will also match for example a newline.

If you don't want to match crossing lines, you can exclude that in the negated character class.

Anchoring the pattern to the start of the string, and optionally repeating the whole character class:

```
^[^;\r\n]*__ctrl1_.*\(
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^;\r\n]*` Match optional chars other than `;` or a newline
- `__ctrl1_` Match literally
- `.*\(` Match a `(` char in the rest of the line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/szW4Gb/1).

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: ***Additional horizontal white space class: `[^\S\r\n]`***
> `(?m)^(?![^\S\r\n]*;).+` https://regex101.com/r/XIWMbn/1

Don't use `\s*`. Using it will spans blank lines that will be included in the output.

---

It's all about the lines disqualification.
And given that only the `;` is the first visible character in the unwanted lines,
it would suggest that horizontal white space is the only characters allowed
before the semicolon when checking a line for disqualification.

Here is the way to quickly find qualifying lines, by checking for disqualification first.
The only difference is what is deemed a horizontal white space.

> ***Using a tab and space:***
> `(?m)^(?![ \t]*;).+` https://regex101.com/r/iEAoiB/1

> ***Using the PCRE `\h` construct:***
> `(?m)^(?!\h*;).+` https://regex101.com/r/rELN7u/1

> ***Using the ASCII hex codes:***
> `(?m)^(?![\x09\x1c-\x20]*;).+` https://regex101.com/r/tdbA0N/1

> ***Using the full Unicode hex representation of what \h matches:***
> `(?m)^(?![\x{9}\x{1C}-\x{20}\x{A0}\x{1680}\x{2000}-\x{200A}\x{202F}\x{205F}\x{3000}]*;).+` https://regex101.com/r/CQxtuk/1

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the first token `[^;]`, essentially saying don't match lines starting with ';'?

No, because that expression isn't anchored to the beginning of the line, so you're searching for a line that contains a character that is not `;`. You probably want:

```
^[^;].*__ctrl1_.*\(
```

That is, a line that begins with a character that is not `;`, followed by anything, followed by `__crtl1_`, followed by anything, followed by `(`.

Comment: This also matches `<spaces>;__ctrl1_(` along with any number of blank lines before it.

Comment: That's correct. It matches lines that begin with *anything* other than a `;`, so it would also match `zzzzz__ctrl1_`, `happy new year__ctrl1_`, etc.

Comment: Yeah but specifically it matches `<spaces>;` plus whatever you want.  Which violates the rule _**I want to only match lines that do not have a preceding ; in them, in other words only match line 2**_, like `<spaces>;` plus whatever you want. Not too hard to understand ?